# Creating TRIGGER giving errors (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a trigger in my mysql database but I keep getting an error. This is my Query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_counters AFTER INSERT ON cheats_main FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM meta_info;
    INSERT INTO meta_info (system_id, system, game_count, cheat_count) VALUES (
        SELECT id, system,
        (SELECT count(g1.id) FROM cheats_games g1 WHERE g1.system = s.id) AS games_counter,
        (SELECT count(c2.id) FROM cheats_main c2 JOIN cheats_games g2 ON g2.id = c2.game_id
        WHERE g2.system = s.id) AS cheats_counter 
        FROM systeme AS s
    );
END;
```

The MySQL table "meta_info" has this structure:

```
system_id | system | game_count | cheat_count | created
```

The error I keep getting is:

> MySQL said: Documentation 1064 - You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Line 3 is:

```
DELETE FROM meta_info;
```

And when I delete this line I get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT id, system,
>           (SELECT count(g1.id) FROM cheats_games g1 WHERE g1.system ' at line 4

Line 4 in this case is:

```
SELECT id, system (...)
```

The inner SELECT works just fine. I get a result table with these columns:

```
id | system | games_counter | cheats_counter
```

Any help is appreciated .Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define another delimiter than `;`. Otherwise the DB will stop the trigger definition at the first `;` which would be incomplete

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_counters AFTER INSERT ON cheats_main FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM meta_info;
    INSERT INTO meta_info (system_id, system, game_count, cheat_count)
        SELECT id, system,
        (SELECT count(g1.id) FROM cheats_games g1 WHERE g1.system = s.id) AS games_counter,
        (SELECT count(c2.id) FROM cheats_main c2 JOIN cheats_games g2 ON g2.id = c2.game_id
        WHERE g2.system = s.id) AS cheats_counter 
        FROM systeme AS s;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

And if you use a select in an insert statement then use it like this

```
insert into t1(col1, col2)
select a, b from t2
```